# Do you have to pay taxes on the free stock you get from a Robinhood referral link if you don't sell it?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks

I signed up for a Robinhood account with a referral link and got a free stock. I've searched all over the internet to see if I have to pay taxes on the gifted free stock. I can confirm 100x over that if you DO sell it, it is subject to taxation. My question is do I have to pay taxes for acquiring it if I do NOT sell it. It's seeming like I don't pay taxes on it if I don't sell it but I can't explicitly confirm that anywhere. I'm from the USA. Denver, CO.

EDIT: assume no dividends as I know those are taxable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do you have to pay taxes on the free stock you get from a Robinhood referral link if you don't sell it?

Yes. https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/invite-friends-get-free-stock/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210813124129/https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/invite-friends-get-free-stock/)):

> The cash value of the stock at the time you claim it may be reported as “Other Income” on a 1099-Misc form, if applicable. Any gains or losses on the sale of the stock are reported as capital gains or losses. You can check the original value of each stock you receive in your Statements & History.